# How to avoid page breaks within knitr kable tables in html

Tags: knitr, page-break, kable

Is there a way to tell knitr that kable tables in html should not be broken across pages when printing the html file.
More generally, how can I create html files from Rmd files forcing page breaks in printed html at given positions

Answer (score 0):

Check out `pagedown` https://pagedown.rbind.io/.  It's designed for paginated HTML output.